# TYPO3 Menu Double up

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have this custom menu setup based on the default section menu. When testing on one content element, it looks good... When I add a second content element to the page both get added to each menu item.

Anyone know what's going on here?

```
tt_content.menu.20.3.1.sectionIndex.useColPos = -1    
tt_content.menu.20.101 < tt_content.menu.20.3
    tt_content.menu.20.101 {
      1.NO {
        stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT
        stdWrap.cObject {
          table = tt_content
          select {
            pidInList.field = uid
          }
          renderObj = COA
          renderObj {      
            10 = FILES
            10 {
              stdWrap.wrap = <div class="menu-img">|</div>
              references {
                table = tt_content
                fieldName = image
              }
              renderObj = IMAGE
              renderObj {
                file {
                  import.data = file:current:uid
                  treatIdAsReference = 1
                  width = 100c
                  height = 100c
                }
                altText.data = file:current:alternative
                titleText.data = file:current:title
                stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
              }
              maxItems = 1
            }
            20 = TEXT
            20.field = header
            30 = TEXT 
            30.field = rowDescription
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is currently outputting:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="link1"><img/>Heading1Desc1<img2/>Heading2Desc2</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2"><img/>Heading1Desc1<img2/>Heading2Desc2</a></li>
<ul>
```

What it should be:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="link1"><img/>Heading1Desc1</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2"><img2/>Heading2Desc2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about your CONTENT object.
your selection is strange:

```
      select {
        pidInList.field = uid
      }
```

you select all tt_content elements which are in the page with the uid of the current content element.
And your rendering is executed for each record found.

Do you really need to select the contentelement with a `cObject` again? I think in the menu it should be the current context.

---

add on:
I would try something like this to render the image before the text (which should be available by default):
`before` just for the image instead of `stdWrap` with a full query of all CEs and with a COA for all fields.

**have a look to the correct fieldname!**

```
1.NO {
    before.cObject = FILES
    before.cObject {
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="pic">|</div>
        references {
            table = tt_content
            uid.data = uid
            // 'image' or 'media' or ...  ???
            fieldName = image
        }
        renderObj = IMAGE
        renderObj {
            stdWrap.wrap = <div class="pic">|</div>
            file {
                import.data = file:current:uid
                treatIdAsReference = 1
                width = 150c
                height = 150c
            }
            altText.data = file:current:alternative
            titleText.data = file:current:title
            #params = class="menu-img"
            // don't do a link inside a link  =:-O
            #stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
        }
        maxItems = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost, are you saying I shouldn't have a cObject at all?

Comment: I think you do not need it. especially not for the title, as the title is used anyway. if you want to insert an image you can use `.before` or `.beforeImg`(see [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenuitem/Index.html)) You may find some inspiration [here](https://forum.typo3.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=739572&) so this example is about pages.

Comment: The COA part contains an image and a couple of fields like `field.rowDescription`. I can't get the image or fields to work without  `CONTENT`

Comment: I have updated the example to more clearly show what I am going for.

Comment: independent what fields you want to render: **your selection is wrong!** for each menu-entry you select all CEs. so with each CE more you will get one more entry and a repetition of all CEs. The HMENU object does a loop over all CEs and for each menuentry your CONTENT object loops over all (/the same) CEs to render your definition (`renderObj = COA`)

Comment: Can you please give me an example doing it without the cObject? I have tried every way except the right way.

Comment: I enhanced my answer

Comment: I tried it like this but it renders an empty `<div class="pic"></div>`

Comment: FAL is a bitch and you may need to extract files by hand. use the FILES object (I inserted into my answer).

Comment: Still empty and I'm pretty sure the field name is image. I also tried adding an `after` with a simple `10.field = rowDescription` and this also renders nothing.

Comment: you may test it with outputting any information (as TEXT object) to see what is available.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this many different ways and cannot get it working with the image and fields. So instead I have simply patched my original code using by adding: `tt_content.menu.20.101.maxItems = 1` and adding a wrap to the `renderObj`.

I know this is not how it should be done, but it works for now. But if anyone knows the correct way of doing it let me know!